# 8hours renamed php session lost data after 30 minutes

Tags: php, session, session-timeout

My default PHP session is 30 minutes.

I got this first code :

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params(28800);
session_name('TEST');
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);

$_SESSION['test'] = 'jam';
?>
```

And this second one :

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params(28800);
session_name('TEST');
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);

echo $_SESSION['test'];
?>
```

The fact is, my session is lost after 30 minutes without activity.

Timed example :

```
00:00 : run first script
00:10 : run seconde script : i got "jam"
00:20 : run seconde script : i got "jam"
00:40 : run seconde script : i got "jam"
01:11 : run seconde script : session is lost
```

Hope you can give me any clue to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#109077) at `session_set_cookie_params()` page in PHP Manual, and see if that helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Cookie lifetime is only one part of the equation. The server-side session storage is the other. Make sure that [`session.gc_maxlifetime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) is set high enough as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting the lifetime of the cookie, that has nothing to do with the actual lifetime of the session data. If you're using the default session save handler that saves sessions to the filesystem, the lifetime of the session data is controlled by [session.gc_maxlifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) directive. You can override this value with [ini_set](http://php.net/ini_set) like this:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 28800);
```

Do note that if you also have other scripts that use sessions and they share the same save path for sessions, then the minimum gc_maxlifetime is used for all sessions in that directory. Hence if you want to change the gc_maxlifetime value, that usually means you also want to specify your own path where the sessions are stored. You can do so with the [session_save_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) function:

```
session_save_path('/path/to/your/sessions');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer,
I need 2 different sessions on my website : a 30min session for the front part and a 8hours session for the admin part. If I defined a specific path for my session using session_save_path() ( by the way is there any relationship with the path I can define using session_set_cookie_params() ? ), how do I precise which session is concerned by my ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 28800); ?

Comment: Do the sessions need to be stored between public and admin part? If the answer is yes, then you must make the sessions last 8 hours for both of them. The session.gc_maxlifetime concerns the sessions whose save path you set in the same script. You can set different save paths for the public and admin parts, and that way you can also have different lifetimes for the sessions.